# Error on opening ASP website

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6, msxml3

We changed the server of our ASP website and in new setting browsing the website returns this error:

msxml3.dll error '80072ee2'

The operation timed out

/error404.asp, line 41 
This is lines that I think returns error:

```
  Set XML=Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
  XML.SetOption 2,13056
  XML.SetTimeouts 90000, 90000, 90000, 90000
  XML.Open "POST", website &"/catalog/page.asp?id="& R("CTLMtree_id") &"&rnd="& rnd(), False
  XML.Send(Request.Form)
  Response.Write XML.ResponseTExt
  Set XML=Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the `website & &"/catalog/page.asp` page exists ?

Are you sure that the Msxml2 dll has been registered.

Do you have other msxml?.dll's on the server? Try another version.

What happens if you increase the `SetTimeouts` values ?

Just a things thoughts that I would try.
But please format your code (indent each line with 4 spaces), so that we at least can see what the actual codes is.